# how to fix sonar issue: stream is not closed when stream is really closed but in lambda

Tags: java, lambda, stream, sonarqube

Sonar raises the issue that fileStream is not closed in the below code. However it is, but in the lambda expression.

```java
try {
    final InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(copy);
    return (OutputStream outputStream) -> {
        int n;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((n = fileStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        fileStream.close();
    };
} catch (IOException exception) {
    //...
}
```

When I change it and use try-with-resource pattern then I get the exception: *java.io.IOException: Stream Closed* in the line of reading fileStream:

```java
try (final InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(copy)) {                
    return (OutputStream outputStream) -> {
        int n;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((n = fileStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }                    
    };
} catch (IOException exception) {
    //...
}
```

Thus the second solution resolves the bug detected by sonar, however it just doesn't work as fileStream is closed before lambda code is invoked.

What would you suggest to fix it?

Comment: In case of an exception, the method might jump out before the outputStream.close() call is done. Add the close command to the catch block or use a try-with-resource to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by @Krashen, your first version could throw an exception before `close()` is called.

Your section version creates the `InputStream` in a try-with-resources in *this* method and then tries to return it as part of the lambda expression. But a try-with-resources ensures its resources are closed, and as far as I can tell, that close happens just before the method exits. Explicitly, by the time the caller receives the `return`ed lambda, the `InputStream` has already been closed.

So... your best bet is to either extract your logic from the lambda and return the results, or assign the lambda results to a variable and then return that variable. Doing the latter will likely raise an issue from S1488 (Local variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown) which I would simply close Won't Fix.